# ConTeXt fails to find SVGs on macOS when space is in directory path

Tags: macros, context

I'm trying to make a PDF of a tex document that references some external SVGs and JPGs. This is the command I am using:

```
context --nonstopmode --batchmode --path=styles main.tex
```

This command creates a PDF with the SVGs embedded properly as long as there are no spaces in the file path.

However, if there is a space in the path, the JPGs are still fine, but I get an error like this for the SVGs:

```
** (inkscape-bin:47420): WARNING **: Can't open file: /Users/test/Library/Mobile (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape-bin:47420): WARNING **: Can't open file: /Users/test/Library/Mobile (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape-bin:47420): WARNING **: Can't open file: Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sync/ebooks/mybook/media/svg/1f601.svg (doesn't exist)
```

The path that causes the problem is iCloud Drive (com~apple~CloudDocs):

```
/Users/test/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sync/ebooks/mybook/media/svg/
```

Normally I would just make a path without spaces... except I want to keep the files in iCloud Drive, and the iCloud Drive path has a space in the directory name by design (sigh).

I tried making a symlink without a space in the path like this:

```
 /Users/test/Library/MobileDocuments/com~apple~CloudDocs/Sync/ebooks/mybook/media/svg/
```

But Inkscape conversion still gives the error "Can't open file" because it can't parse a path with spaces in it.

If I move all the files off iCloud Drive (to a directory with no spaces in the path), then it works fine.

Is there a way to get ConTeXt (Inkscape) to understand paths with spaces in them?